# "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.19045 in the manifest list entries"

Tags: docker, github, large-language-model, gpt4all

Newbie at Docker, I am trying to run go-skynet's LocalAI with docker so I follow the documentation but it always returns the same issue in my terminal (in admin mode):

> '**no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.19045 in the manifest
> list entries**'.

It appends when I use the commands of the documentation `docker-compose up -d --pull always` or `docker-compose up -d --build`
I also tried to run an other model of LocalAI (rwkv) with the command `docker build -t rwkv-converter -f Dockerfile.build .` from its file and I have the same issue.

Is there someone who can help me with that please ?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this as well. Found this on another site and it fixed my issue.  Go to Settings->Docker Engine and change the "experimental": value to true.  Then Apply and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it on Win10, you should use

`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

instead of

`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022`

in your `Dockerfile`. This is because Windows inside container must be roughly of same version as real Windows you're running it on.